# What's the difference between unshare() and copy()?

Tags: arrays, swift

Both `unshare()` and `copy()` are used for copying an array, but I can't see the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Unshare

As it says on [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_109) `unshare` is to **ensure that the copy of the array is unique**, so when you call `unshare` you get non shared copy of the array, that could be the same array if that was the only reference to the array.

## Copy

On the other hand `copy` forces the copy of the array and returns **a new array containing the copied items**.

So if you want to have 2 independent copies of the array you should use `copy` on other case you can use `unsare` to ensure the array has no other references.

Comment: i was reading the book and when i came to this section i want to search in SO. i understood what book says however still cannot see the difference. copy or unshare gives you a array which if you alter any object in the new one does not affect the source or vice versa. that is why couldn't see the difference.

Comment: Well, with `copy` you get a new copy of the array, different from the original source, and if you modify that one the source is not modified. With `unshare` you can get a new copy, if there where more references to that array, but you keep the same reference if that was the only one, so in the case of `unshare` if there were no other copies, you will modify the original array as no copy will be done... I hope now it's more clear...

Comment: thank you for explanation, i understand in the theory but that doesn't change in result both are same.

Comment: Also note that `unshare` operates on the receiver, modifying it in place. `copy`, on the other hand, returns a new array. This means, amongst other things, that `unshare` cannot be called on constants whereas `copy` can.

Answer (score 4):

`unshare()` will do nothing if the callee is already not shared. `copy()` will copy it regardless.

Comment: So `unshare` is like _“copy if needed”_?

Comment: Not strictly but you could think of it that way.

Answer (score 3):

This has changed with Beta 3.  unshare() and copy() have both been removed from Array.  Arrays are now copy-on-write with the default behavior being much like always calling unshare().

http://blog.human-friendly.com/swift-arrays-beta-3-hooray

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_109):

> If you simply need to be sure that your reference to an array’s contents is the only reference in existence, call the unshare method, not the copy method. The unshare method does not make a copy of the array unless it is necessary to do so. The copy method always copies the array, even if it is already unshared.

Basically, unshare won't do anything if it's the only reference. Copy will do it either way.

Answer (score 2):

Per the Swift Programming Guide (pg 298):

> “If you simply need to be sure that your reference to an array’s
>   contents is the only reference in existence, call the unshare method,
>   not the copy method. The unshare method does not make a copy of the
>   array unless it is necessary to do so. The copy method always copies
>   the array, even if it is already unshared.”

Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language.” iBooks. https://itun.es/us/jEUH0.l