# Alternatives to pointers in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, pointers, sprite-kit

I'm using SpriteKit to make a game. When two sprites of a specific type collide, I want to make note of one of the sprites, and then have that sprite updated later in the game.

Using pointers, I would essentially do the following. When the two objects collide, I would set some global pointer to the address of the sprite I want to keep track off. Then later, when the modification function is called, it would modify whatever is being pointed to at that address, essentially modifying the sprite that collided.

I would prefer to not use pointers though, since Swift discourages direct access to memory. I can't pass the sprite by reference to the modification function since the modification function (didSimulatePhysics) isn't called by my code.

Thanks!

Comment: "I can't pass the sprite by reference to the modification function since the modification function (didSimulatePhysics) isn't called by my code" – this seems orthogonal to the fact that you have pointers to your objects anyway (Objective-C interop *requires* that). So just declare a variable of the appropriate type – it will be a pointer under the hoods. Also, try doing this without a global variable. If you think global variables are a solution to your problem, then there's always a better way to solve it.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Sorry, I'm a bit confused. What do you mean I have pointers to my objects anyway? I don't have any "UnsafePointers" - isn't that what Swift calls pointers? What do you mean by "declaring a variable of the appropriate type will be a pointer under the hoods"? Are all objects actually pointers? Sorry, I have no experience with Objective-C so I'm a bit confused.

Comment: Yes, all Objective-C objects are pointers. An "unsafe" pointer is not the only type of pointer.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant It's not an Objective-C object though. It's a Swift object (SKSpriteNode)

Comment: SpriteKit's primary interface is Objective-C. It *is* written in Objective-C (and perhaps in C++ too).

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I see, thank you that did the trick. One last question: if all objects are pointers by default, how do I simply make a copy of an object?

Comment: You invoke its "copy" method.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Awesome, thanks a lot! If you post your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.unshare()` and `.copy()` like that:

```
var valueA = [1,2,3,4]
var valueB = valueA
```

Now if you change valueA, valueB will be changed too:

```
valueA[1] = 4 // valueA and valueB are now equal to [1,4,3,4]
```

But if we use `.unshare()` method:

```
valueB.unshare()
```

Then valueB is unshared so if we change valueA, valueB won't chang:

```
valueA[1] = 2 \\ valueA == [1,2,3,4] && valueB == [1,4,3,4]
```

Or you can use `.copy()` method:

```
var valueC = valueA.copy()
```

It's the same as:

```
var valueC = valueA
valueC.unshare()
```

Comment: You can find more about  `.unshare()` and `.copy()` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044610/whats-the-difference-between-unshare-and-copy